# Using "as in/ like in"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I was watching a video and the guy in the video said this :

> "... All the methods I have talked about in the past are correct but
>   there is an alternative path ***like many things in*** training" (he
>   is talking about different exercise methods.)

I wonder why using "like many things in" above sounds idiomatic but using "like the case in" in the sentence below sounds unidiomatic ?

> ***1- As is the case in*** a plethora of English-language papers, the
>   writer chose this extremely common construction. (This was written by
>   a native speaker.)
>
> ***1a- Like the case in*** a plethora of English-language papers, the writer chose this extremely common construction. (I was told that this was not at all idiomatic.)

Comment: The speaker is *speaking*, and what he's got to deal with here is a fairly simply concept that actually "requires" quite complex phrasing in English to be "correctly" expressed. I think probably the best of a bad bunch would be *...but **as with** many things in training, there is an alternative path.* But you shouldn't over-analyse it - who's to say whether extending that to ***as is the case with*** is any more "correct", or makes the meaning any clearer?

Answer (score 1):

like is for a comparison.

- He is like my brother. [[He resembles my brother as regards his behavior]].

**as** in **as is the case** is merely introducing an example of an actual case or other thing. There is no comparison.

- As is true for most French people, Americans like cheese.

like many things in training = similar to other things in training. That is comparing methods to other things one encounters in training.

**Now, the trick is to realize that in everyday speech**, **people will often use *like* instead of **as**.**

- Like many French people, Americans like cheese. [comparison]
  FOR:
- As with many French people, Americans like cheese. [What applies to French people also applies to Americans.]

It is a question of language register. (formal versus informal)